# How to copy a file from USB drive to my local chrome web app folder in chrome device using api

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I want to copy a file from usb device, in my local installed chrome web application.
 1. I tried using api under chrome.usb.
 2. i am able to list, connect and open the device.
 but how to transfer a file?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [chrome.fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem)?

Comment: Yes!, i tried this only first. but there is no such option to copy a file from usb or copy .zip file.

Comment: Eh? Open the file, read it, write to a new location.

Comment: yeah that's fine for text files, what about image, video files?

Comment: Use [arrayBuffer or blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) and read in small chunks (1MB, for example).